# One line object creation

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Well i've come to a situation where i'm enclosed to create and populate a javascript object in a single statement, anyway, i might use another method but i find interesting to know if this can be achieved.

The main reason is, this assignation must happen in a context where i can't use the javascript if statement, so i had to use the three parameter statement ( ? : ) (sorry my english here, i bet this is not the name of this).

So, having this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: someArray-->
  <Input Type="Text" data-bind="value: ( $root.something() ? ['Some Values'][model.index]:'No value' )">
<!-- /ko -->
```

Where model.index is an integer property that corresponds to a value that is related to that generated -via php- array.

As said before, i think i'm gonna pass these two parameters (indexs and values) to another model.function and create the indexed object i need, but it is particularly interesting to know if there is a way to do somewhat like:

```
 (((($a={})[0]="Wow, i belong to '$a'")[1]="Yeah!, me too")[2]="But this does not behave as expected ;(")
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it only works up to this part  `($a={})[0]="Wow, i belong to '$a'"`

since it returns string not object so you cant do `(..)[1]` to it

also this is not a good practice to do.

you can create inline `object` like

```
$a = { 0: "Wow, i belong to '$a'", 1: "Yeah!, me too", 2: "Now me too" }
```

and use index

```
($a = { 0: "Wow, i belong to '$a'", 1: "Yeah!, me too", 2: "Now me too" })[model.index]
```

**OR**

inline `array` (which is more suitable to your situation)

```
($a = ["Wow, i belong to '$a'", "Yeah!, me too", "Now me too"])[model.index]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i forgot to explain why inline arrays won't work, that's because the server might give arrays which indexs start not from 0, so KO could have indexs starting from N, and these generated arrays need to start from N.

Comment: so then create object with `N` as starting key

Answer (score 0):

I really thought in @JAG's answer, but trying to do it i got this error, does this have a logical explanation?

(Sorry for using the answers feature, but comments can't include images)

[image]

(Chrome's console) latest version, Windows 7.

Comment: you doing it wrong... once object `$a` created, you can access its values like `$a[key]`

Comment: That's quite evident just looking at this error, it is just i see no reason for this being this way...